# Is possible download a images from Google Earth Engine to my PC desktop?

Tags: image, collections, download, desktop, google-earth-engine

I need download **60 images** from a specific Landsat mission. My problem is that the memory in the Google drive folder is of 15 gigas. So, somebody knows a way for **download directly to my pc desktop** or the download just can be do in a Google drive? Thaks

Answer (score 1):

If you need whole images, you're probably better off accessing the tiffs from the collections in Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-datasets/landsat

If you want to cut them using Earth Engine first, then you'll have to just export them 1 by 1 to Drive and delete each one after you've download it to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response.  I will follow your recommendations.